# Build Firestore transaction operation

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have a delete operation as shown below on Firestore. It is working fine. But could you tell me how can I use a `transaction` for doing that? At this moment if there is any failure it does partial delete.

```
  async delete(project: DtoProject): Promise<void> {
    await this.fireStore.doc<Project>(`projects/${project.id}/`).delete();
    const budgetGroupsQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/budgetGroups`).get();//budgetGroups
    budgetGroupsQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (doc: any) => {
      await this.fireStore.doc<BudgetGroup>(`projects/${project.id}/budgetGroups/${doc.id}`).delete();
    });
    const budgetsQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/budgets`).get();//budgets
    budgetsQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (doc: any) => {
      await this.fireStore.doc<Budget>(`projects/${project.id}/budgets/${doc.id}`).delete();
    });
    const categoriesQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/categories`).get();//categories
    categoriesQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (doc: any) => {
      await this.fireStore.doc<Category>(`projects/${project.id}/categories/${doc.id}`).delete();
    });
    const transactionsQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/transactions`).get();//transactions
    transactionsQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (doc: any) => {
      const notesQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/notes`).get();//notes
      notesQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (n: any) => {
        await this.fireStore.doc<Note>(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/notes/${n.id}`).delete();
      });
      const photosQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/photos`).get();//photos
      photosQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (p: any) => {
        await this.fireStore.doc<Photo>(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/photos/${p.id}`).delete();
      });
      await this.fireStore.doc<Transaction>(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}`).delete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get all the doc references that you want to delete and then iterate through each one them using **Promise.all** in the transaction.

Like below:

```
  deleteAll(arrayOfDocReferencesToBeDeleted){
    return this.db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
      return Promise.all(arrayOfDocReferencesToBeDeleted.map(async (ref) => {
        await transaction.delete(ref);
      }));
    }).then(() => console.log('success')).catch(() => console.log('error'))
  }
```

In your case you can change your function to this code:

```
async delete(project: DtoProject): Promise<void> {

    //first get all the doc referencs that you want to delete

    var  firstReferenceToBeDelete = this.fireStore.doc<Project>(`projects/${project.id}/`);

    //get all the docs from the collection
    const budgetGroupsQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/budgetGroups`).get();//budgetGroups
    //map the doc references to an array
    var groupsRef = budgetGroupsQuerySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { return this.fireStore.doc<BudgetGroup>(`projects/${project.id}/budgetGroups/${doc.id}`) });
    //repeat it until you have all the doc references that you want to delete

    const budgetsQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/budgets`).get();//budgets
    var budgetsRef = budgetsQuerySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { return this.fireStore.doc<Budget>(`projects/${project.id}/budgets/${doc.id}`) });

    const categoriesQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/categories`).get();//categories
    var categoriesRef = categoriesQuerySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { return this.fireStore.doc<Category>(`projects/${project.id}/categories/${doc.id}`) });

    const transactionsQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/transactions`).get();//transactions

    var notesRef = [];
    var photosRef = [];
    var lastRefs = [];

    transactionsQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (doc: any) => {
      const notesQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/notes`).get();//notes
      var notes = notesQuerySnapshot.docs.map((note) => {
        return this.fireStore.doc<Note>(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/notes/${note.id}`)
      });
      notesRef.concat(notes);

      const photosQuerySnapshot = await this.authenticationProvider.firestoreDb.collection(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/photos`).get();//photos
      var photos = photosQuerySnapshot.docs.map((photo) => { return this.fireStore.doc<Photo>(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}/photos/${photo.id}`) });
      photosRef.concat(photos);

      lastRefs.push(this.fireStore.doc<Transaction>(`projects/${project.id}/transactions/${doc.id}`));
    });

    //make a single array with them
    var arrayOfDocReferencesToBeDeleted = [firstReferenceToBeDelete].concat(groupsRef, budgetsRef, categoriesRef, notesRef, photosRef, lastRefs)

    //after you have an array with all your doc references you can iterate them in the transaction

    return this.db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
      return Promise.all(arrayOfDocReferencesToBeDeleted.map(async (ref) => {
        await transaction.delete(ref);
      }));
    }).then(() => console.log('success')).catch(() => console.log('error'))
  }
```

Of course you should break this function in another functions but this will work.

Comment: It seems really nice. I'll apply this to my project in coming days and will let you know if I'll have any issues. Thanks a lot for your feedback :)

Comment: You are welcome, I’d like to know your feedback and work together if you find any issue.

Comment: Sorry, friend Still I didn't get any chance to test this since I'm very busy to finish 3rd milestone of this project.We'll not implement this feature on this MS. But I'll test this within this week and will let you know. Thanks.